# Why does it follow that $X * Y$ is $(n + m + 1)$-connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be an $n$-connected CW complex and $Y$ a $m$-connected CW complex. Why does it follow that $X * Y$ is $(n + m + 1)$-connected?

Comment: WHat is $X*Y$, can you remind me the meaning of this notation?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $X\wedge Y$?

Comment: The join $X * Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \wedge X \wedge Y$, so following @iwriteonbananas' comment, it suffices to prove that if $X$ is $n$-connected and $Y$ is $m$-connected, then $X \wedge Y$ is $(n+m)$-connected.  Can you complete the proof from here (hint: use cellular approximation)?

Comment: @JHF $X\wedge Y$ is actually $(n+m+1)$-connected though, which is off-putting.

Comment: @iwriteonbananas Whoops, you're absolutely correct.